# How can I ignore duplicate values in another column when using GROUP?

Tags: mysql, count, group-by

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
    DATE(`timeStamp`),COUNT(*)  
FROM 
    `wf`.sh`
WHERE 
    (DATE(`timeStamp`) >= curdate()- INTERVAL 31 DAY)   
GROUP BY 
    DATE(`timeStamp`) 
HAVING 
    COUNT(DATE(`timeStamp`)) > 0  
ORDER BY 
    DATE(`timeStamp`) ASC;
```

The purpose of this query is to retrieve the amount of users online in my system per day, in the space of a month.

Example dataset:

```
uID     timeStamp
1       2016-11-28 00:27:01
1       2016-11-28 01:10:15
1234    2016-11-28 02:50:00
2       2016-11-28 06:11:09
47      2016-11-28 08:32:48
1246    2016-11-28 09:51:47
```

In its current format, this query returns the count of rows with duplicate dates, for example:

```
timeStamp   COUNT(*)
2017-01-29  256
2017-01-30  224
2017-01-31  240
2017-02-01  95
2017-02-02  136
```

I have another field `uID`; I need to modify my query so that `GROUP` also ignores rows with a duplicate `uID` field for each day. I tried creating another `GROUP BY` but was given an error that 'incorrect GROUP BY clause' (or something of that nature).

Can this be done via pure MySQL?

Comment: Would be nice to know the reason behind the *two* drive-by downvotes on my question that have occurred within the last couple of hours..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subselect

```
SELECT 
    visitDate,COUNT(*)  
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT DATE(`timeStamp`) as visitDate, uID FROM `wf`.sh`) alias_t
WHERE 
    (visitDate >= curdate()- INTERVAL 31 DAY)   
GROUP BY 
    visitDate
HAVING 
    COUNT(visitDate) > 0  
ORDER BY 
    visitDate ASC;
```